# Backpropagation through 2D transposed convolution layer

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, backpropagation, transposed-convolution

I’m looking for an explanation for the backwards pass in a conv2d transpose layer. My main problem is that the deltas from the next layer are larger than the input of the previous layer. Hence, I can’t simply convolve the deltas over the input within the boundaries of it. Of course, I could just remove rows/columns from the deltas but that doesn’t seem like the proper way to do it.

Comment: Could you maybe clarify the question a bit, including the formulas that you're struggling with?

Comment: I’ve added the details here. Unfortunately, I’ve not been able to find a mathematical explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576279/forward-and-backward-pass-in-tranpose-convolution-layer

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but I got stuck on this and found this question. I am posting my solution, to help others who stumble across this page. First of all, DO NOT REMOVE ROWS AND/OR COLUMNS.

So deconvolution/ fractionally strided convolution/ transposed convolution (personally I prefer fractionally strided convolution), is literally just reversing the forward and backward pass.

Take an example of stride two and doubling the input size. First, upsample the tensor by adding rows and columns of zeros, then pad accordingly. Now convolve with a stride of one. Notice, this is the same as the backward pass when computing the gradients.
For the backward pass, convolve with a stride of two, then your deltas will be the correct dimensions. Again notice this is just the forward pass.

I'm not writing the math because the internet is saturated with CNN forward and backpropagation equations. These equations are all you need to know, just revise them well and notice fractionally strided convolution is just the reverse, then you will be able to implement in any framework of your choosing.

Hope this helps others, just really pay attention to the backward and forward passes, reverse them, and you will have it.

Comment: Thanks! I've figured it out by myself afterwards. It's really just reversing the processing. I've implemented it from scratch and compared it to tensorflow and the results were identical.